# How to completely disable the default Cursor.TEXT for a TextArea object

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I've tried CSS as well as setting the cursor through scene and the object itself, nothing seems to work it always comes up with that cursor.

I'm not talking about the caret or caret position either, I mean the actual mouse cursor when you hover over a TextArea which I want either removed or changed to the default pointer.

```
textArea.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
.text-area {
    -fx-cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the text area uses a scroll pane internally, your mouse is really over the content of the scroll pane. So this works:

```
.text-area .content {
    -fx-cursor: default ;
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct; it will make it easier for others to find it.